# How to check the type of file in Firebase before downloading?

Tags: python-2.7, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to download a set of images from Firebase Storage.

Before downloading, I need to check the type of Images (i.e. if `.jpeg` only, only then will I need to download).

Can anyone help me with a code in Python?

Comment: There is no Python API for Firebase Storage. You may be able to use the gcloud API for Python: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/gspythonlibrary

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of doing this is actually writing a Storage Security Rule that disallows downloads unless the file has a content type of `image/*`:

```
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/<your-firebase-storage-bucket>/o {
   match /images/{imageId} {
       allow read: if resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
     }
   }
 }
}
```

See more [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files).