# How to upload .m4a to firebase storage using flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

How do I ensure the content type in firebase storage is "audio/m4a"? It is currently being stored as application/json; charset=UTF-8
.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156345/how-to-check-the-type-of-file-in-firebase-before-downloading)

Answer (score 1):

When you use [putFile](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference/putFile.html) to upload the file, be sure to pass a [StorageMetadata](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageMetadata-class.html) object as the second argument.  Be sure set the [contentType](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageMetadata/contentType.html) property of that object to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding @Doug Stevenson [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54068530/10269042) with code.

```
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(
      file,
      StorageMetadata(
        contentType: 'audio/m4a',
        customMetadata: <String, String>{'file': 'audio'},
      ),
    );
```

`ref` is `StorageReference`.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
Future<void> uploadGorsel(XFile filePath,String name) async {
    try {
      String referance =
          '${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}/Record/$name';
      final metadata = SettableMetadata(
          contentType: 'audio/m4a',
          customMetadata: {'picked-file-path': filePath.path});

      storage
          .ref(referance)
          .putData(await filePath.readAsBytes(), metadata)
          .then((p0) async {
        var url = await p0.ref.getDownloadURL();
        print(url);
        print(p0.ref);

      });
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).